# QT QFileDialog.getOpenFileName Cancellation crash

Tags: python, qt, pyqt, pycharm, qtwidgets

I'm a new user of Qt and I'm trying to fix a persistent crashing issue that happens in my 'open file' dialogue. Whenever I open a file dialogue to select a file and decide to hit cancel instead, it causes python to stop working.
This is what the code looks like right now:

```
# get save file
savefile, _ = QtWidgets.QFileDialog.getOpenFileName(self, "Open file", "", "Files (*.mat)")
self.matlocation = savefile
```

I've tried using:

```
savefile, _ = QtWidgets.QFileDialog.getOpenFileName(self, "Open file", "", "Files (*.mat)")
if(!fileName.isEmpty()&& !fileName.isNull()){
self.matlocation = savefile
}
```

but this is still causing crashes. Am I missing something?

Thanks in advance.

**Edit**
It's part of a larger function:
So it's part of a function from a larger .py. The function as it stands starts by loading in a mat file:

```
def loadmat(self):
    from PyQt5 import QtWidgets
    import functions.plotting as plot


    # get save file
    savefile, _ = QtWidgets.QFileDialog.getOpenFileName(self, "Open file", "", "Files (*.mat)")
    self.matlocation = savefile


    # set mat location in GUI box
    self.gui.samplelocBox.setPlainText(self.matlocation)
```

Comment: Can you post more from this code snippet? From these two lines it is unclear what exactly is happening.

Comment: Editted as above - hopefully this is more intuitive!

Comment: Did you try to write with `None` in place of `self`?

Comment: That would require changing almost every line of code in the program which it likely going to cause more issues.

Comment: @Fairbz provide a [mre]